# Spring data JPA repositories not saving to database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to initialise spring-data repositories without using the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation and spring autowiring. In my existing application I have access to a `DataSource` object that I want to use for DB communication. The following code generates an implementation for `TravelAlertRepository` and reads existing rows in the DB. However, whenever I try to update these changes are not shown in the DB. I am also not able to create new rows in the DB.

```
interface TravelAlertRepository extends 
    org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository<TravelAlertVO, Long>{}

class SpringDataRepositories {

private TravelAlertRepository travelAlertRepository;
private javax.persistence.EntityManager entityManager;

SpringDataRepositories() {

  this.entityManager = createEntityManager();
  RepositoryFactorySupport factory = new JpaRepositoryFactory(entityManager);
  travelAlertRepository = factory.getRepository(TravelAlertRepository.class);
}

private static javax.persistence.EntityManager createEntityManager() {

  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
  em.setDataSource(dataSource());
  em.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
  em.setJpaProperties(hibProperties());
  em.setPersistenceUnitName("persistentName");
  em.setPackagesToScan(
    TravelAlertVO.class.getPackage().getName()
  );
  em.afterPropertiesSet();
  return em.getObject().createEntityManager();
}

private static Properties hibProperties() {

  Properties properties = new Properties();
  properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
  properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
  return properties;
}

public static DataSource dataSource() {
  DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

  dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb");
  dataSource.setUsername("mydb");
  dataSource.setPassword("mydb");

  return dataSource;
}
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: How do you add new rows? Did you forget to commit by any chance?

Comment: @VeselinDavidov using travelAlertRepository.save(travelAlertVO)

Comment: ok I gave an answer ;) I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

When using the repository it works in some hibernate cache state so using save() doesn't actually save the object to the database. It marks it in the hibernate as object that needs to be saved.

If you call the flush() method of the entity manager it will send the object to the database but it still will not commit! So you will be able to find it in the database but only if using the same database connection.

In order to see the result in the database you need to commit your transaction. (Hibernate by default waits until the end before sending the data to the database). Try calling the commit() method of the transaction for your entity manager - `em.getTransaction().commit();`

Check this article http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-save-persist-update-merge-saveorupdate

And read that part:

> It is important to understand from the beginning that all of the
>   methods (persist, save, update, merge, saveOrUpdate) do not
>   immediately result in the corresponding SQL UPDATE or INSERT
>   statements. The actual saving of data to the database occurs on
>   committing the transaction or flushing the Session.

Comment: Is there a way to configure something that ensures `em.getTransaction().commit()` is called after each save() ?

Comment: @Veselin Davidov Is that true even if you wrap your repository into a regular non-transactional method stack? Doesn't JpaRepository define save() and the like with @@Transactional, which implies a commit()?